# R - data table considered as factors but it's not

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table, aggregate

This time I'm really puzzled and don't know what to do.
I have a data frame like this one

```
           ID     VALUE1     VALUE2    GROUP    MODEL
    # 1: id_1   0.5697779   17.6100597  Group_A  Model B
    # 2: id_10 246.7413330 6814.7109375  Group_A  Model_B
    # 3: id_100   0.0000000   26.5990372  Group_C  Model_F
    # 4: id_1000   0.0000000    0.0000000  Group_B  Model_D
    # 5: id_101 105.3097610  486.4001160  Group_C  Model_C
    # 6: id_102   0.0000000  108.9007416  Group_C  Model_C
    # 7: id_103   0.1306531    1.0070915  Group_C  Model_F
    # 8: id_104   0.0000000    0.5426522  Group_C  Model_F
    # 9: id_105   0.1352515    1.1137601  Group_C  Model_C
    # 10: id_106   0.0000000    0.2867465  Group_C  Model_C
```

and I need to compute the aggregate value of `VALUE1` and `VALUE2`. So I do

```
agg <- aggregate(cbind(dat[,"VALUE1"],dat[,"VALUE2"]), by = list(dat[,"GROUP"], dat[,"MODEL"]),FUN=sum)
```

but I get

```
Summary.factor(structure(1L, .Label = "VALUE1", class = "factor"),  : 
‘sum’ not meaningful for factors
```

but if I type

```
apply(dat,2,is.factor)
```

gives me

```
ID       VALUE1    VALUE2    GROUP    MODEL
FALSE    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE    FALSE
```

How come? Where am I wrong?

EDIT: with `dput(dat)` I get

```
structure(list(ID = c("id_1", "id_10", "id_100", 
"id_1000", "id_101", "id_102", "id_103", "id_104", 
"id_105", "id_106"), VALUE1 = c(0.56977790594101, 246.741333007812, 
0, 0, 105.309761047363, 0, 0.13065305352211, 0, 0.135251507163048, 
0), VALUE2 = c(17.6100597381592, 6814.7109375, 26.5990371704102, 
0, 486.400115966797, 108.900741577148, 1.0070915222168, 0.542652249336243, 
1.11376011371613, 0.28674653172493), GROUP = c("Group_A", 
"Group_A", "Group_C", "Group_B", "Group_C", "Group_C", 
"Group_C", "Group_C", "Group_C", "Group_C"), 
MODEL = c("Model_B", "Model_B", "Model_F", "Model_D", 
"Model_C", "Model_C", "Model_F", "Model_F", "Model_C", "Model_C"
)), .Names = c("ID", "VALUE1", "VALUE2", "GROUP", "MODEL"), sorted = "ID", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x97b5290>)
  ID          VALUE1     VALUE2 GROUP MODEL
1:     id_1   0.5697779   17.6100597       Group_A       Model_B
2:    id_10 246.7413330 6814.7109375       Group_A       Model_B
3:   id_100   0.0000000   26.5990372       Group_C       Model_F
4:   id_1000   0.0000000    0.0000000       Group_B       Model_D
5:   id_101 105.3097610  486.4001160       Group_C       Model_C
6:   id_102   0.0000000  108.9007416       Group_C       Model_C
7:   id_103   0.1306531    1.0070915       Group_C       Model_F
8:   id_104   0.0000000    0.5426522       Group_C       Model_F
9:   id_105   0.1352515    1.1137601       Group_C       Model_C
10:   id_106   0.0000000    0.2867465       Group_C       Model_C
```

Comment: are you aware that is a data table? if so, why wouldnt you use data table operations?

Comment: well...not really. :) but does it change for my aim?

Comment: just wondering. `apply(dat` converts the object to a matrix which does not hold factors, so you will get false for all your variables. can you add the `dput(dat)` or `str(dat)` to your q

Comment: or  `sapply(dat, is.factor)`

Comment: This question needs to be made reproducible. Use `dput` to give us a copy of your data.

Comment: @mtoto `sapply(dat, is.factor)` gives the same results `FALSE` for all the columns. @rawr `dput(dat)` gives a long output. what are you looking for? so I can print it here

Comment: convert your `data.table` to a `data.frame` first, then it should work

Comment: you are totally right!! Damn it!! so easy! and I didn't think of it at all! well, take out as many ratings as you want! I deserve!!

Comment: ...still I don't get why it was considering as factors my columns

Comment: Why a factor? You were `cbind()`-ing the result of dat[,"VALUE1"] when `dat` was a data.table. The behavior of `[.data.table` (versus `[.data.frame` is quite different when a character vector is given as the j-argument. I would have expected it to get converted to a character value and then I think that `aggregate` converted with `as.data.frame` which in turn made it a factor.

Comment: and after all this the question title is still asking about data.frame. downvoted.

Comment: @42- but `dat[,"VALUE1"]` is not character. so why does it need to convert it as character vector? (I fixed it it's just to better understand how things go)
@ista sorry. it was very late here... :)

Comment: Btw, I checked and `is.data.frame(dat)` gives me `TRUE`. still puzzled...

Comment: As I explained .... `dat[ , "VALUE1" ]` _is_ character when dat is a data.table. And that is so because of the features of the data.table extraction function. Please read the data.table FAQ. (Should be that difficult, since it's the second item.

Comment: I just missed that it was a character for a data.table...